# Make delete remove four spaces at the beginning of the line (un-indent) in emacs

Tags: emacs

In emacs, I want delete to remove four spaces at the beginning of the line, so that I can easily un-indent text.  I have TAB set to insert four spaces (in the relevant modes), and this would be helpful.

For example, if I have

```
|        _
```

where `|` represents the beginning of the line (I had to add this to make the markdown render it correctly), and `_` represents the cursor, and I press delete, I want to get

```
|    _
```

**EDIT:** I just discovered that this already happens in certain modes, such as python-mode.

**EDIT 2:** I think my original question was confusing people.  I want something like this.  Suppose I have

```
|        my text_
```

and the cursor is at the end of the line (shown by the _).  If I type DEL, I want to get

```
|        my tex_
```

(obviously).  But if I have

```
|        m_
```

and I type DEL, I want

```
|        _
```

and if I type DEL *again*, I want

```
|    _
```

To think of it another way, I want to treat four-space tabs as if they were real tabs as far as the delete key is concerned.

Comment: are you looking for `M-m` by any chance.?

Answer (score 2):

How about this snippet of code, which you could bind to whatever you want:

```
(defun remove-indentation-spaces ()
  "remove TAB-WIDTH spaces from the beginning of this line"
  (interactive)
  (indent-rigidly (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position) (- tab-width)))
```

Note, if `tab-width` doesn't match up with what you want, hard code it to -4.

And if you want this bound to <kbd>DEL</kbd>, you can do:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "DEL") 'remove-indentation-spaces)
```

or, define it in the appropriate mode-map like:

```
(define-key some-major-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 'remove-indentation-spaces)
```

*Updated to toggle between deleting a char and 4 spaces:*

```
(defun remove-indentation-spaces ()
  "remove TAB-WIDTH spaces from the beginning of this line"
  (interactive)
  (if (save-excursion (re-search-backward "[^ \t]" (line-beginning-position) t))
      (delete-backward-char 1)
    (indent-rigidly (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position) (- tab-width))))
```

Comment: Well, that's close to what I want.  But I want to bind this to DEL, so that it deletes the last character normally, but deletes four spaces if all the characters before it in the line are spaces.

Comment: @asmeurer Updated to do what you want.